# Check if MS Access is Installed

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for a way to check if MS Access is installed and then if it is not Exit Sub or finish running the rest of the module.  I came across this bit of code, but I am unsure of how to adapt it to suit my needs.

```
Function ApplicationIsAvailable(ApplicationClassName As String) As Boolean 
' returns True if the application is available 
' example: If Not ApplicationIsAvailable("Outlook.Application") Then Exit Sub     
Dim AnyApp As Object   
    On Error Resume Next   
    Set AnyApp = CreateObject(ApplicationClassName)   
    ApplicationIsAvailable = Not AnyApp Is Nothing   
    Set AnyApp = Nothing   
    On Error GoTo 0 
End Function
```

Thank you in advance if anyone is able to assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up getting this to work not long after I posted the question.  In case anyone was curious, I used the above code to declare the function and then within my module that I was running I used this bit of code to determine if it was available.

```
If ApplicationIsAvailable("Access.Application") = False Then
MsgBox ("You must have Microsoft Access installed to use this function")
Exit Sub
End If
```